# SSDT ColumnStoreIndex WITH option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I created a ColumnStore index manually in the SERVER using with (maxdop = 1) in the script. However, then i pull that change into my database using schema compare is doesn't recognize that option. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that MAXDOP is a deploy-time setting. It's used at the time the index is created / altered, but no metadata about the option is stored in the server. For this reason SSDT ignores this option as well as the ONLINE option.